# Why is Javascript giving result as Number instead of True/False for expression?

Tags: javascript

I was rambling with JavaScript code in my application today when I observed something strange.

```
var someVar = 25; 
var anotherVar = 50; 
var out = (anotherVar == 50 && someVar); 


console.log(out) // outputs 25 and not true or false;
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: `(anotherVar == 50 && someVar == 25)`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As stated on [MDN's Logical Operators page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), the `&&` operator:

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `&&` returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

In your case, *expr1* (`anotherVar == 50`) is true (not false), so it returns *expr2* (`someVar`), which is `25`.

It doesn't return `true` or `false` because *expr2* isn't a Boolean value.

The [ECMA-262 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11) notes:

> The value produced by a `&&` or `||` operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions.

Comment: he could use '!!' (anotherVar == 50 && !!someVar) //true

Comment: This is, by the way, why you sometimes see defaults done like `arg1 = arg1 || "default";` (as long as false-y values (like `null` and etc) are not valid values)